# Importing modules in pycharm

Tags: python, module, pycharm, python-import

I am completely new to pycharm, and have what is probably a very stupid question.

I have created two files and saved them to one directory; one is a settings file, which includes a class Settings, that I would just like to import into the other file, which will hold my main code.

My main file looks like this:

```
import pygame
from settings import Settings

class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
```

and my settings file looks like this:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
```

however when I run the main file I get an AttributeError type object 'Settings' has no attribute 'screen_width'.

Is there something I need to configure in order for the files to locate each other?

Comment: You're missing the parenthesis when you instantiate the class `Settings`. So you need `self.settings = Settings()`

Comment: Doh! I knew I was being stupid! Thank you so much